# Android 4.4.2 reverse tethering onto MacBook Air via Bluetooth PAN - not connecting to internet

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth, tethering

I'm trying to throttle my device's network connection while testing it on Android studio. My strategy will be to try and reverse tether the phone to my macbook Air so the computer acts as a hotspot. The computer will be connected to the internet via wifi, and should be acting as an internet hotspot for any paired devices.

However the internet connectivity is never set, so the android device never connects online.

What I did:

- Turn on network sharing via Wi-Fi, checked the Blue Tooth Pan Option.
  [image]
- Paired the devices (i.e. the phone is detected by the macbook and vice/versa.
- Set up a static IP on the blue tooth pan configuration (see image).
  [image]

And here is my Bluetooth setup on the device:
[image][image]

My phone is not rooted and frankly I'd rather not have to root it - but for some reason the phone is not detecting Bluetooth on the macbook air. But the macbook does detect the phone and is able to send files to it.

What gives?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you dont need to set blueetoth on you mac preferences, that is for use PAN as client, you want to use PAN as host on your mac.

Comment: I've the exact same problem. I', not able to access internet from my phone, and it says it using bluetoth for internet access.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: I have same problem. MacBook Pro with MacOS High Sierra 10.13.2. Trying to connect to Samsung Galaxy S5 to share purchased WiFi on airplane from Mac to Phone via Bluetooth PAN. Any solution?

Comment: Is this solved? I am having the same issue. My MacBook Air and my Android phone are paired. But I am not getting internet on my mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

I did working reverse tethering from MacBook Pro El Capitan to android mobile. Sharing the network Macbook Pro with Bluetooth PAN.

The trick is, to have android mobile rooted. First connect your mobile to any wifi, change advanced network options in mobile as Static IP,  192.168.2.1  router 192.168.2.1  DNS 8.8.8.8  8.8.4.4.

With terminal emulator apk, enter: su dhcpcd bt-pan

Now you can close your wifi in mobile.

be sure you have bluetooth pan configured as "Use DHCP with manual address"  option matching same IP and DNS your put in android.

Note; of course android paired with the macbook, and sharing network and sharing bluetooth options active.

All working very stable.

Answer (score -1):

Recently, I've tried to check transfer packages by proxy-ing from Mac to Android device. I think Bluetooth shouldn't be used for setting the shared internet but instead you should just share from your Ethernet to Wi-Fi.

(I tried to put in a comment as this is more like it since I don't have any images or a concrete explanation... but it wouldn't allow it).

Comment: I think this setup should be possible, receive the internet from wifi and use from an android phone thorugh a bluetoth link (PAN)